# How to get link URL on onClick in a QWebView?

Tags: qt, onclick, pyqt, pyside, qwebview

How do I get a link's URL when clicking on the link?

If I have a link in the A tag, it's simple: just connect `linkClicked(const QUrl&)` signal to specific slot.

But if I have a table with an "onClick" event on its cell (generated html: `"&#60;td onClick=\"window.location.href='" + link_ + "';\"` ......blahblahblah"), it's not working. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's name suggests, the [linkClicked](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebview.html#linkClicked) signal is only emitted whenever a *link* is activated.

But you can intercept all navigation requests by reimplementing [acceptNavigationRequest](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebpage.html#acceptNavigationRequest):

```
class WebPage(QtWebKit.QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WebPage, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setLinkDelegationPolicy(QtWebKit.QWebPage.DelegateExternalLinks)

    def acceptNavigationRequest(self, frame, request, type):
        print('Navigation Request:', request.url())
        return False

...

webview.setPage(WebPage())
```

But note that **all** navigation requests are passed through this method, so your implementation should return `True` whenever it does not intend to handle the request.

Comment: This does not seem  to handle javascript navigations like `window.location = '...';` any idea how to catch those?

Comment: @Inverse. It works fine for me - i.e. `window.location.href=url` works the same as `window.location=url`, and everything goes through `acceptNavigationRequest`. If you have a code example that produces different behaviour, I suggest you post it as a new question.